# Security Error when connecting to ws://localhost:23120/install from internet page

Tags: javascript, websocket, internet-explorer-11

I have a web page communicating with my .net application installed on my computer via websocket.
During development I had my page on http://localhost:8009 and everything worked fine with 'ws://localhost:23120/install' in Chrome, FF, IE11.

Now after I deployed my page to public internet server with HTTPS protocol I have an error in IE11: SecurityError. That's it. No additional information.
An Error executing

```
const webSocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:23120/install');
```

Can that be becourse I open HTTPS page and try to connect to not secure websocket?
Or anything else?

Comment: I would recommend if you are working with Dotnet and Websockets. Take a look at signalr. Make's it a lot easier.

Comment: After deployed, whether this issue only occurs in IE browser? Try to test it using Chrome and Firefox. Besides, in my opinion, after deployed we should use the IP address or the URL with domain name to connect the WebSocket, instead of using localhost, please try to test it.

Answer (score 0):

In short. Yes. It is because it is now secure. You should be using

```
wss://yourdomain.com/install
```

Remember to setup on the server to allow secure websockets.

Comment: you should add that the websocket must be configured to enable secure connections. SSL on Websocket is not enabled by default

Comment: @LelioFaieta, could you explain? You mean I should set my webSocket Server with certificate?

Comment: @Kiksen, and what if I want to connect to localhost application installed on my computer? I don't want to connect to yourdomain.com/install